# Exchange requirements and MAPI support in Outlook 2011

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

I am looking at Outlook for Mac (in Office 2011).

I wanted to find out what versions of Exchange are supported, as well as whether MAPI is supported.

I googled and also searched the Microsoft site. I also checked in wikipedia, but it was probably too soon.

I found [announcement about Outlook for Mac](http://www.officeformac.com/.59b7a1cc)

I found the [system requirements on the official site](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/outlook), but they don't say anything on these topics.

I saw some forum traffic saying: MAPI is not supported, but there was no attribution, so I won't bother to quote it.

Can anyone point me to some official documents that address these concerns?

Comment: I am successfully running Outlook 2011 with Exchange 2007. I couldn't find any official documents other than my single test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help feature in the Outlook 2011 Setup Wizard states that only Exchange 2007 SP1 or higher is supported. Furthermore only EWS (Exchange Web Services), and not MAPI, is supported.

Comment: An online version of the help page I am referring to can be found here: http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/bf4e9965-e1ec-4b97-8967-eac4eeaead70